# Date manipulation in awk variable : Non Military Format

Tags: linux, unix, awk

In the mentioned code : `| awk '{ print $1, $2 }'`
**AWK $2** is having "**Thu Nov 19 17:00:00 2015**" in it. I want to manipulate this date String there only in inline awk in Non Military format "**Thu Nov 19 05:00:00 PM 2015**". Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should give you the expected format:

```
kent$  echo "Thu Nov 19 17:00:00 2015"|awk '{d=$0;cmd="date -d\""d"\" +\"%a %b %d %r %Y\"" ;cmd|getline $0;close(cmd)}7'
Thu Nov 19 05:00:00 PM 2015
```

#### Here you go:

```
kent$  echo "FOO,Thu Nov 19 17:00:00 2015"|awk -F, '{d=$2;cmd="date -d\""d"\" +\"%a %b %d %r %Y\"" ;cmd|getline $2;close(cmd);print "col1:"$1 RS "col2:"$2}'        
col1:FOO
col2:Thu Nov 19 05:00:00 PM 2015
```

Comment: Actually the Solution is pretty awesome, but what i am looking for is when the case is like that when i am already having this string within $2 of an AWK, will I be able to call another AWK within it, Trying the below code

Comment: |`awk -F"," '{print $2"\t"$3"\t"$6}'|awk -F"[][]" '{print $2 $6 `awk -v d=$8 '{d=$0;cmd="date -d\""d"\" +\"%a %b %d %r %Y\"" ;cmd|getline $0;close(cmd)}7'`}'`....where $8 having that date string. In this way its not working.

Comment: Basically what i need is to pass the $8 value of an AWK to another AWK within it.

Comment: @TamoghnaMajumdar have you read my update? What is left to you just adjust the output format. Try to understand the codes, just 3 statements in total. In your above comment, you have 3 awks... I have no idea what do you want to do. but I think to your original question, I have provided a working answer.

Comment: @TamoghnaMajumdar no, you are WAY off from understanding awk or the solution. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "Thu Nov 19 17:00:00 2015" |
awk '{
    split($4,t,/:/)
    if (t[1]<12) {
        ampm="AM"
        if (t[1]==0) {
            t[1]=12
        }
    }
    else {
        ampm="PM"
        if (t[1]>12) {
            t[1]=t[1]-12
        }
    }
    $4=sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d %s",t[1],t[2],t[3],ampm)
} 1'
Thu Nov 19 05:00:00 PM 2015
```

Comment: I like what you did. A couple of edge case: 12:00 needs ampm="PM", and 00:00 needs t[1]=12

Comment: fixed thanks. I dont the OPs looking anyway though - he seems kinda fixated on making this complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Just with GNU awk:

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, '
    BEGIN {months = "..JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"}
    function monthName2Num(monthname) {
        return index(months, monthname)/3
    }
    function convertTime(datetime,          a,t) {
        split(datetime, a, "[ :]+")
        t = mktime(a[7]" "monthName2Num(a[2])" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6])
        return strftime("%a %b %e %r %Y", t)
    }
    { print $1, convertTime($2) }
' <<'END'
something,Thu Nov 19 17:00:00 2015 
END
```

outputs

```
something,Thu Nov 19 05:00:00 PM 2015
```