# Passing AWK variable value to nested AWK

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Is it possible to pass an AWK variable within another AWK block in the same inline? Will the Below code Work Where $8 is having value **Mon Nov 16 16:00:00 2015**

```
|awk -F"[][]" '{print $2, $6, ${echo $8|awk '{d=$0;cmd="date -d\""d"\" +\"%a %b %d %r %Y\"" ;cmd|getline $0;close(cmd)}7'}}'
```

Comment: You are WAY off. awk is not shell. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and try again after you read the first couple of chapters.

Comment: Yep, I understand, i will surely check that. But as I need this kind of solution in urgent basis is there anyway where a nested AWK can be implemented or it simply not possible?

Comment: You might have better luck getting someone to untangle this for you if you give a sample of the input you have and the output you're trying to get from that.

Comment: $8 is carrying "Mon Nov 16 16:00:00 2015" as input and looking for "Mon Nov 16 04:00:00 PM 2015" as output.

Comment: Tip: when someone asks you to clarify, do it by editing the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two questions that you have asked today, this question actually asks to combine the two answers in one statement.
This can be achieved easier (i.e., without an external call) by modifying Ed Mortons answer to [Date manipulation in awk variable : Non Military Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807928/date-manipulation-in-awk-variable-non-military-format) and embedding it into your awk script:

```
awk -F"[][]" '{ split($8,a,/[: ]/)
    p = "AM"
    if(a[4]a[5]a[6] > 120000) {
        p = "PM"
        a[4] = a[4] > 12 ? a[4] - 12 : a[4]
    } else if(a[4] < 1) {
        a[4] = 12
    }
    datetime=sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d %s",a[4],a[5],a[6],p)
    print $2, $6, a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "datetime" "a[7]}'
```